# Deriving expression of electric field at a point above centre of hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics

I have been trying to derive the expression for electric field due to a solid uniformly charged hemisphere at a point which is a certain distance above the centre. I have identified that the differential element will be a disc. I have no idea how to proceed further. I know the expression for electric field due to a disc. Please guide me further.

Comment: Hi Adithya and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework question. I started learning electrostatics st college. Out of interest, i started to find electric fields due to different objects at different points. But this case of hemisphere is bugging me. There are 3 variables which change if i take the differential strip to be a disc. The radius, distance from the point of interest and the angle subtended by the discs at the point of interest keeps varying continuosly. So i thought i of getting help from here. I dont want the solution. I just want to know how to convert the 3 variables into a single variable.

Comment: Do you want to find out the electric field along the axis. Try to be more specific in your question.

Comment: Yes. Im interested in finding the field due to the hemisphere at a certain point directly above the centre of hemisphere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let us divide the hemisphere into solid discs, of infinitesimal width $dx$ and radius r. Let us also denote the radius of the hemisphere as R and the distance from each disc from the centre of the sphere as x (by sphere I mean the sphere from which the hemisphere was obtained). Consider now a point lying on the axis, at a distance $x'$ from the centre of the sphere. Now you know the E field due to an individual disc is $E_{disc}=\frac{Q}{4\pi r\epsilon_0} (1-\frac{x'-x}{\sqrt{(x'-x)^2+r^2}})=\frac{Q}{4\pi \sqrt{R^2-x^2}\epsilon_0} (1-\frac{x'-x}{\sqrt{(x'-x)^2+R^2-x^2}})$ from Pythagoras, and that Q is $\rho \pi r^2 dx$, where $\rho$ is the charge density. Now the integral for a single variable follows, since R and x' are constant.